# How to bind command using ReactiveUI and WPF

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I'm trying to learn ReactiveUI in WPF and I'm confusing on how to bind command using Reactive UI binding (not default Xaml binding).
I read on ReactiveUI documentation that the correct way is to use the following instruction:

```
this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.MyCommand, v => v.myControl);
```

Now if I have in MainWindowView.xaml (View):

```
        <Button x:Name="TestButton" Command="{Binding Click}" />
```

in MainWindowView code-behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindowView : Window
    {
       public MainWindowView()
       {
             InitializeComponent();
             DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
       }
    }
```

and in MainWindowViewModel (ViewModel):

```
    class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
       public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ClickCommand { get; }

       public MainWindowViewModel()
       {
           ClickCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(ClickMethod);
       }

       void ClickMethod()
       {
           // Code for executing the command here.
       }
   }
```

I don't know where insert and how to compose the first instruction :

```
this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.MyCommand, v => v.myControl);
```

for my specific context.

Thank you very much for and an answer.

Comment: Usually you place rxui bindings in the code behind constructor of your view. So in your case MainWindowView. You may want to use the WhenActivated() method which will dispose your binding when the view no longer exists. It's in the docs how to do that.

Comment: To @GlennWatson point you add code bindings in the code behind of the xaml page.

These are generally created in the constructor.  And we have WPF samples https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/blob/master/wpf/getting-started/ReactiveDemo/MainWindow.xaml.cs that will show you how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The WPF samples referenced by Rodney Littles in the comment above are very good. For your case it should be something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindowView : ReactiveWindow<MainWindowViewModel>
{
    public MainWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        this
            .WhenActivated(disposables => {
                this
                    .BindCommand(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.ClickCommand, v => v.TestButton)
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
    }
}
```

Make sure you derive from `ReactiveWindow<MainWindowViewModel>` instead of `Window`. Also, instead of `DataContext`, use the inherited property named `ViewModel`.

Comment: You don't need to necessarily use `ReactiveWindow<MainWindowViewModel>` but it is one of the easier approaches.

Comment: @GlennWatson 

Comment: Thank you all. I tried as suggested and It works as I wanted. I had to read this post https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1684 to understand how to inherit ReactiveWindow in xaml view.